# Error while compiling with clang/clang++ [-Werror,-Wrange-loop-constrcut]

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

I'm trying to build a c++ project. While doing so with g++ the project compiles fine. However if I try to compile with clang I get the error:

```
ec_read_plan.h:135:19: error: loop variable 'op' creates a copy from type 'const std::pair<ChunkPartType, ReadPlan::ReadOperation>' [-Werror,-Wrange-loop-construct]
     for (const auto op : read_operationss_{
ec_read_plan.h:135:8: note: use reference type 'const std:pair<ChunkPartType, ReadPlan::ReadOperation> &' to prevent copying
     for (const auto op : read_operations) {
```

Code is below, I have put a comment next on the line that is giving the error:

```
protected:
    void recoverParts(uint8_t *buffer,
                      const std::bitset<Goal::Slice::kMaxPartsCount> &available_parts) const {
        typedef ReedSolomon<slice_traits::ec::kMaxDataCount, slice_traits::ec::kMaxParityCount> RS;

        int k = slice_traits::ec::getNumberOfDataParts(slice_type);
        int m = slice_traits::ec::getNumberOfParityParts(slice_type);
        int max_parts = k + m;

        RS::ConstFragmentMap data_parts{{0}};
        RS::FragmentMap result_parts{{0}};
        RS::ErasedMap erased;
        RS rs(k, m);

        int available_count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < max_parts; ++i) {
            if (!available_parts[i] || available_count >= k) {
                erased.set(i);
            } else {
                available_count++;
            }
        }

        for (const auto op : read_operations) {  //ERROR appears to be here
            data_parts[op.first.getSlicePart()] = buffer + op.second.buffer_offset;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < (int)requested_parts.size(); ++i) {
            if (!available_parts[requested_parts[i].part]) {
                result_parts[requested_parts[i].part] = buffer + i * buffer_part_size;
            }
        }

        rs.recover(data_parts, erased, result_parts, buffer_part_size);
    }
```

Why am I getting such an error with Clang and how can I fix this? Thank you.

For anyone who may want to reproduce the error, the source code is here: https://github.com/lizardfs/lizardfs. Afterwards do:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CC=/usr/bin/clang++
cd lizardfs
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/lizardfs
make
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's unlikely that anyone will be able to telling why you are "getting such an error". This is because the shown code does not meet the requirements for a [mre], as explained in the [help], so it's not possible for anyone to cut/paste the given code, ***exactly as shown*** and reproduce your exact compilation error.

Comment: Just provided the way to get the error by building from source.

Comment: @MarkShaio By making a [mre] as Sam asked for you would make it so much easier for people to help you.

Comment: I think the error message explains the error well, it even suggests a solution to fix it.

Comment: It's very unlikely that someone is going to download an entire project on github in order to answer this question. The best way to improve the chances of getting some help with a problem is to make it as easy as possible for everyone else to reproduce the problem, and the easiest way to do so is to come up with a short code sample, no more than a few pages. Some years ago I found a bug in xwfm4 window manager. Instead of telling the XFCE maintainers to go and download a few thousand lines of code, I whipped up a 20-line bug reproducer, they jumped on it and fixed the bug.

Comment: Perhaps you want `for (const auto& op : read_operations)` instead.

Answer (score -2):

It turns out the error has to do with the clang and clang++ versions. As mentioned gcc had no problems compiling. By default my machine uses clang/clang++ version 10. I tried using version 11 but also had the same problem. I therefore installed version 9 of clang/clang++ and tried compiling again and it worked.

If you happen to have the same problems make sure to run the following commands or have them in the `~/.bashrc` file and run `source ~/.bashrc` after installing version 9 of clang/clang++

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang-9
export CC=/usr/bin/clang++-9
```